# How to set the background color of all ListView Items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview

I have got the following for setting the background color for a single item when clicking on it:

```
        // Get the listView on the Home Fragment
        val contactList = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listViewContacts)
        // Create IDs for each element
        val id : Int = R.id.txtListElement

        // Fill the ListView with the custom contact_list_template
        arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.contact_list_template, id, contactSimple)
        contactList.adapter = arrayAdapter

        contactList.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view,
                                                                            position, _ ->
            val selectedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            val itemIdAtPos = adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(position)


            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_200))
            ...
        }
```

But how can I set the color for every object inside the ListView?
I tried
`contactList.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white))` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: The code you mentioned in your last sentence is the correct way to do it, but maybe you're calling it at the wrong place? Can you show your complete code where you did it this way?

Comment: The code in the last sentence somehow changes the color of the complete ListView, not the items. I have inserted it before the `contactList.onItemClickListener`
Basically I want to make the clicked item purple_200 and all others white.

Comment: your question is not clear .. wen you want to set the color for every item in the list ??  by clicking any button any item or you want to set color for every item by default ??

Comment: So I want to make a clicked item appear in a different color then all the others. Then if you click on another item this one should be highlighted. So that only the last clicked item has a different color.

Comment: I think that a better approach could be to implement your own `BaseAdapter` or use a `RecyclerView`, use a variable to keep track of the last clicked and change the background when binding the item layouts.

Comment: @LucaPizzini Okay, good. But is there also a way to do it with ListView? I have everything working, just this color stuff not ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your custom `BaseAdapter` for the `ListView`. (I assume that the `contact_list_template` XML contains a `TextView` with id `title`).

```
class ListViewContactAdapter(
    private val contactList: List<String>
) : BaseAdapter() {

    private val lastClicked = ""

    override fun getCount(): Int = contactList.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): String = contactList[position]

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.contact_list_template, parent, false)

        val holder = ViewHolderContact(view)
        val contact = getItem(position)

        holder.title.text = contact

        if (contact == lastClicked) {
            // Selected background
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, ...))
        } else {
            // Unselected background
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, ...))
        }

        view.setOnClickListener { 
            lastClicked = contact
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        return view
    }

    class ViewHolderContact(itemView: View) {
        val title = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
    }
}
```

You can then set the adapter of the list with:

```
val contactList = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listViewContacts)
contactList.adapter = ListViewContactAdapter(contactSimple)
```